# Network request failed React native expo api post error

Tags: react-native, post, fetch, expo, mern

Hi there I am trying to post some data to my mongo db using express and node js and I am getting following error however data is working fine with postman I am trying to save buffer data to my mongodb

Network request failed

at node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:123:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:379:16 in callTimers
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:414:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:113:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:365:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

here is my frontend code

frontend.js

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  Picker,
  Platform,
  Alert,
  input,
  //fetch
} from "react-native";

//const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
//router.use(bodyParser.json());
//router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
//import ImagePickerExample from "../components/CameraFunc";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';



export default class Sellnow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChangePetName = this.onChangePetName.bind(this);
    this.onChangePetTitle = this.onChangePetTitle.bind(this);
    this.onChangePetContact = this.onChangePetContact.bind(this);
    this.onChangePetPrice = this.onChangePetPrice.bind(this);
    this.onChangePetDescription = this.onChangePetDescription.bind(this);
    this.onValueChangeCat= this.onValueChangeCat.bind(this);
    this.onValueChangeCity= this.onValueChangeCity.bind(this);
    this.onFileChange = this.onFileChange.bind(this);
   // this.pickImage = this.pickImage.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    // State
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      title: "",
      contact: "",
      price: "",
      description: "",
      selectedcat:"",
      selectedcity:"",
      imgforsell:"",

      //collection categories
      category: [
        
        {
          itemName: "Select Category...."
        },
        {
          itemName: "Pets Food"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Pets Products"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Pets Accessories"
        }
      ],

      // cities category
      cityCategory:[


        {
          itemName: "Select City...."
        },
        {
          itemName: "Islamabad"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Rawalpindi"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Lahore"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Peshawar"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Karachi"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Quetta"
        }

      ]
    };
  }


  /*componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/PetsBazar/pets/' )
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          name: res.data.name,
          title: res.data.title,
          contact: res.data.contact
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }*/
  onChangePetName(e) {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  }
  onChangePetTitle(e) {
    this.setState({ title: e.target.value });
  }
  onChangePetContact(e) {
    this.setState({ contact: e.target.value });
  }
  onChangePetPrice(e) {
    this.setState({ price: e.target.value });
  }
  onChangePetDescription(e) {
    this.setState({ description: e.target.value });
  }
  // categories function
  onValueChangeCat(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedcat: e.targetvalue })
  }

  // city function
  onValueChangeCity(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedcity: e.targetvalue })
  }

  onFileChange(e) {
    this.setState({ imgforsell: e.targetvalue})}

  // uploading Image


  _getPhotoLibrary = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      base64: true,
      exif: true,
      aspect: [4, 3]
    });

    

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ imgforsell: result });
      
      
    }
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      imgforsell: this.state.imgforsell
    });
  };



  onSubmit  (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /*const petsObject = {
      name: this.state.name,
      title: this.state.title,
      contact: this.state.contact,
      price: this.state.price,
      description: this.state.description,
      selectedcat:this.state.selectedcat,
      selectedcity:this.state.selectedcity,
      imgforsell:this.state.imgforsell
      };
*/
      const formData = new FormData();
      /*formData.append( 'imgforsell', {
    
       // name: new Date() + '_profile',
        uri: this.state.imgforsell,
        type: 'image/jpg',
       
      });*/

      
      formData.append("name", this.state.name);
      formData.append("title", this.state.title);
      formData.append("contact", this.state.contact);
      formData.append("price", this.state.price);
      formData.append("description", this.state.description);
      formData.append("selectedcat", this.state.selectedcat);
      formData.append("selectedcity", this.state.selectedcity);

      formData.append("imgforsell", this.state.imgforsell);


      
      


      fetch(
        `"http://${
          Platform.OS === "android" ? " 192.168.10.11" : "localhost"
        }:4000/pets/addpets"`,
        //'http://http://10.0.2.2:4000/pets/addpets',
       
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: formData,
      //   headers: {
        //  "content-Type": "application/json"
     // },
      //body:JSON.stringify({formData})
          
          
         // headers:{"Content-type":"application/json"}
        }
      )
        .then((res) => {
          if (!res.ok) {
            return Promise.reject(res);
          }
          return res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.setState({
            name: "",
            title: "",
            contact: "",
            price: "",
            description: "",
            selectedcat: "",
            selectedcity: "",
            imgforsell: "",
          });
        });


      /*  axios
  .post(
    `http://${
      Platform.OS === "android" ? "192.168.10.11" : "localhost"
    }:4000/pets/addpets`,
    formData
  )
  .then(({ data }) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err.toJSON());
    // res.status(500).json(err)  don't do this, it's not Express
  })
  .finally(() => {
    this.setState({
      name: "",
      title: "",
      contact: "",
      price: "",
      description: "",
      selectedcat: "",
      selectedcity: "",
      imgforsell: "",
    });
  });*/
  }



  

  render() {
   
    const {imgforsell} = this.state
    
  
   
    return (
      <View>
      <ScrollView
        nestedScrollEnabled={true}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.formContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.conText}>Please Fill the Below Form </Text>

            <View style={styles.borderForm}>
              <Text style={styles.formText}>Your Name</Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.formInput}
                multiline
                placeholder="Please Enter Your Name"
                maxLength={15}
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.onChangePetName}
                blurOnSubmit={true}
                onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name })}
              />

              <Text style={styles.formText}>Category</Text>

             { /*<CategoryDropList />*/ }

             <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
            
             <Picker
          
           itemStyle={styles.itemStyle}
            mode="dropdown"
           style={styles.pickerStyle}
            selectedValue={this.state.selectedcat}
           // onValueChange={this.onValueChangeCat.bind(this)}
           //onValueChange={(selectedcat)=>this.setState({selectedcat})}
           onValueChange={(itemValue,itemIndex)=> this.setState({selectedcat:itemValue})}
        
          >
            {this.state.category.map((item, index) => (
              <Picker.Item
               
                color="black"
                label={item.itemName}
                value={item.itemName}
                index={index}
              />
            ))}
          </Picker>
         
          </View>

              

              <Text style={styles.formText}>Pet/Product Title</Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.formInput}
                placeholder="Enter Product Title"
                maxLength={15}
                value={this.state.title}
                blurOnSubmit={true}
                onChange={this.onChangePetTitle}
                onChangeText={(title) => this.setState({ title })}
              />

              <Text style={styles.formText}>City</Text>

              {/*<CityDropList />*/}

              <View style={styles.viewStyle}>

              <Picker
          
           itemStyle={styles.itemStyle}
            mode="dropdown"
           style={styles.pickerStyle}
            selectedValue={this.state.selectedcity}
           onValueChange={(itemValue,itemIndex)=> this.setState({selectedcity:itemValue})}
        
          >
            {this.state.cityCategory.map((item, index) => (
              <Picker.Item
               
                color="black"
                label={item.itemName}
                value={item.itemName}
                index={index}
              />
            ))}
          </Picker>

          

          </View>
              <Text style={styles.formText}> Contact Number </Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.formInput}
                placeholder="Phone Number"
                inputType="number"
                maxLength={11}
                keyboardType="number-pad"
                blurOnSubmit={true}
                value={this.state.contact}
                onChange={this.onChangePetContact}
                onChangeText={(contact) => this.setState({ contact })}
              />
              <Text style={styles.formText}>Price</Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.formInput}
                multiline
                placeholder="Enter Price"
                inputType="number"
                keyboardType="number-pad"
                blurOnSubmit={true}
                maxLength={7}
                value={this.state.price}
                onChange={this.onChangePetPrice}
                onChangeText={(price) => this.setState({ price })}
              />
              <Text style={styles.formText}>Image of Product</Text>

              {/*<ImagePickerExample />*/}

             

              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={this._getPhotoLibrary.bind(this)}>
              <Text style={styles.btnTxt}> Choose File</Text> 
                </TouchableOpacity>
        
                {imgforsell ? (
              <Image source={{ uri: imgforsell.uri }} style={styles.uploadimgstyle} />
            ) : (
              <View/>
            )}
            
              
              <Text style={styles.formText}>
                Description(Optional max 150 words)
              </Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.descriptionInput}
                multiline
                placeholder="Describe your product"
                maxLength={150}
                blurOnSubmit={true}
                value={this.state.description}
                onChange={this.onChangePetDescription}
                onChangeText={(description) => this.setState({ description })}
              />
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={this.onSubmit}>
                <Text style={styles.btnTxt}>Submit</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```